# Finding child fragment by Tag inside another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I hava a fragment that is the parent of another fragment. I am adding the fragment child like this:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.list_container, new SwipeableFragment(), FRAGMENT_LIST_VIEW).commit();
        transaction.addToBackStack(FRAGMENT_LIST_VIEW);

 return view;
}
```

Later, I have a method in my parent fragment that needs to find the child. So I'm doing like this:

```
final Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_LIST_VIEW);
```

But always returns null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this code with the code given below:

```
// Your Code:
final Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_LIST_VIEW);


// Replace with this:
final Fragment fragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_LIST_VIEW);
```

Hopefully it will work!